# "below of=" ? more than one block?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a block `c` under two blocks `a & b`. So far I'm able to do it for only one block

```
\node [block, below of=a]    (c)    {filter};
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`. It'll be much easier for us to understand your problem this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please always post complete code starting from `\documentclass{..}` and ending at `\end{document}`. I don't know how `block` is defined.

Your question is not clear. Whether `a` ,`b` and `c` are one below the other or `a` and `b` side by side with `c` below them at the center?

Please note that `below of=a` is deprecated. you should use `below = of a` instead with `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. Here are the possibilities.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (a) {Coffee};
      \node [below = of a] (b) {Sugar};
      \node [below = of b] (c) {Filter};    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
      \node (a) {Coffee};
      \node [below left = of a] (c) {Filter};
      \node [above left =  of c] (b) {Sugar};
    \end{scope}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can control the distances manually like `below left = 1cm and 2cm of a`. For details refer `pgfmanual`.